# Convert NaN values to NULL, or NaN to 0 in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have values in registries that contain NaN values (they come from MATLAB). How would I convert them to NULL, or preferably, 0, in SQL?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you have imported them into a SQL Server table

```
update tbl
set theColumn = NULL
WHERE theColumn = 'NaN'
```

This converts the column values to NULL if they are the string 'NaN'
For the column to contain 'NaN', it must be varchar, so if you prefer 0, that would be the string '0'

```
update tbl
set theColumn = '0'
WHERE theColumn = 'NaN'
```

In a select statement, you can use either of

```
SELECT NULLIF(theColumn, 'NaN') as NullifiedTheColumn, ...
SELECT CASE theColumn when 'NaN' then '0' else theColumn end as ZeroedTheColumn, ...
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT NULLIF('NaN', ColumnName)
```

example

```
DECLARE @d VARCHAR(3) ='NaN'

SELECT NULLIF('NaN', @d)
```

for 0

```
DECLARE @d VARCHAR(7) ='NaN'

SELECT CASE WHEN @d = 'NaN' THEN '0' ELSE @d END
```

Answer (score 2):

How about `CASE WHEN IsNumeric(column)=0 THEN 0 ELSE column`?

Comment: How would it look within a `Select statement `

Comment: `SELECT CASE WHEN IsNumeric(column)=0 THEN 0 ELSE column END`

Comment: Run this  :-)  SELECT ISNUMERIC('2d4')

Comment: IsNumeric will still suffice for his purposes in spite of its general inadequacy.